# How to send data into post request parameters for the following JSON data?

Tags: swift, xcode

I have checkboxes required for product return on a page with more than one product, and when I press a checkbox, I want to store the id and quantity of the selected product in the items in the post parameter that I want to send.But, I cannot send the correct data. How can I send correct data?

```
{
 "reasonId" : "001",
 "cancel" : "true",
 "description": "" ,
 "items": [
    {
        "id": "874a8064-bebf-41c3-98a8-6ac39a54156a",
        "quantity" : 480
    },
    {
        "id": "d7af8722-58cb-4bd0-9927-47de44ba2e0b",
        "quantity" : 2
    },
    {
        "id": "f799d66e-cfcd-4f2b-9603-1facf2fedbea",
        "quantity" : 1
    },
    {
        "id": "5ea0c31f-952a-4fbc-b623-9086030193ad",
        "quantity" : 17
    }
]
}
```

I can print the id and quantity of the selected product.

```
private func createCheckBox(_ model : OrderDetailItems, tag: Int) -> UIView {
let rootView = UIView()
returnItemCount = model.definition?.count
var checkBox: ViewCheckLabel!
checkBox = ViewCheckLabel(text: "",
                            range: "",
                            action: {
    // CHECKK SELECT OR NOT SELECT
    checkBox.buttonCheck.checkboxAnimation {
        if checkBox.buttonCheck.isSelected {
            print(model.quantity)
            print(model.id)
        } else {
            
        }
    }
})
```

This is my post request

```
  func cancelOrderApi() {
        if let parentVC = parentViewController as? MyProfileViewController {
            parentVC.startActivityIndicator(mainView: parentVC.view)
            
                        let parameters : Parameters = [
                            "reasonId" : reasonId,
                            "cancel" : isOrdrReturnable,
                            "description": "",
                            "items" : ""
                        ]
            
            NetworkLayer.request(Router.returnOrder(parameters, orderReturnId ?? "")).responseDecodable(of: OrderCancel.self) { (response) in
                            
                            switch response.result {
                                case .failure(let error):
                                    Logger.shared.debugPrint("Error while fetching tags: \(String(describing: error))")
                                    return
                                case .success(let response):
                                    if response.code == 200 {
                                        parentVC.showAlert(mesg: response.message ?? "Siparişiniz İade edilmiştir", title: "Başarılı")
                                    } else {
                                        parentVC.showAlert(mesg: response.message ?? "", title: "Hata")
                                        Logger.shared.debugPrint(response.message ?? "")
                                    }
                                    
                                    Logger.shared.debugPrint(response)
                            }
                            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                parentVC.stopActivityIndicator()
                                parentVC.profileTableView.reloadData()
                            }
                        }
                    }
    }
```

Comment: Your "items" parameter is [String : Any]  and not a String. Try inserting "items": ["id": "874a8064-bebf-41c3-98a8-6ac39a54156a",
             "quantity" : 480]

Comment: How can I store selected data like the following JSON? @Mr.SwiftOak

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not entirely sure what you want to achieve, since the question is unclear, however here is a tip how to create `Data` object (can be later inserted into Url request) from your JSON file. Firstly manually copy your JSON file somewhere to your project and give it name `yourJSONFile`  , then you can create `Data` object with create `createDataFromJson()` function.

```
func createDataFromJson() -> Data? {
    if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "yourJSONFile", ofType: "json") {
        do{
            let data = try Data(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: path), options: .mappedIfSafe)
            return data
        } catch {
            print("catched : \(error.localizedDescription) ❌")
            return nil
        }
    } else {
        return nil
    }
}
```